# What does the error missing begin marker mean

Tags: ssh, continuous-integration

When trying to ssh to a server hosting some code, I get

```
debug1: Trying private key: /home/ubuntu/.ssh/build_key.rsa
debug1: key_parse_private2: missing begin marker
```

What does "missing begin marker" mean?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306)

Comment: It may appear to be off-topic, but it's not in my case since I have to execute this process automatically inside my code and I get these particular issues affecting my program.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is not an error. It is just harmless debug information that is printed during the parsing of different key types.

Comment: Any info on what it does mean tho? I'm curious as well